# jquery: execute function since screen resolution 650px width

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

Execute this function below only when the screen resolution is at least 650px wide. Otherwise, do nothing.

```
$('.section-box').waypoint(function() {
    $(this).addClass('animated-107s bounceDown');
}, {
    offset: '25%'
});
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can try it.

```
<div class=".section-box" id="myClass">
```

JS

```
//control first open browser
  $(document).ready(function () {
    if( $( window ).width() <= 650 ){

          $("#myClass").addClass("bounceDown");


    } 
  });

  //change browser size
  $( window ).resize(function() {

    if( $( window ).width() <= 650 ){
          $("#myClass").addClass("bounceDown");
    } else {
       $("#myClass").removeClass("bounceDown");
    }
  });
```

Comment: could you please comment your code? i can't see .section-box and .waypoint there - does it disables all jquery commands since screen width 650px?

Comment: hmm.... there is **waypoint**
http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/jquery-zepto/
also "in game" what my code above doing: it adds those classes only then user scrolls to certain element on a page. not before. does your solution reckon with that?